# ORDER BY is not working in the query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a query to get the status as group by and order by. I am getting the results in group by but not in order by. Can you help .

Here is my query

```
(
SELECT v.STATUS, COUNT(v.STATUS) AS COUNT
FROM mdl_ctx_voucher v
WHERE 
MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(v.timecreated)) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND
MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(v.timemodified)) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND 
YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(v.timecreated)) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND 
YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(v.timemodified)) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY v.STATUS ORDER BY v.`status` DESC
)
UNION
(
SELECT DISTINCT(STATUS),0 as count
FROM mdl_ctx_voucher
WHERE STATUS NOT IN (
SELECT mainQuery.status
FROM 
(
SELECT COUNT(v.STATUS) AS COUNT, v.STATUS
FROM mdl_ctx_voucher v
WHERE 
MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(v.timecreated)) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(v.timemodified)) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(v.timecreated)) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(v.timemodified)) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY v.STATUS ORDER BY v.`status` DESC
)mainQuery) ORDER BY v.`status` DESC
)
```

and I am getting this result without order by.

```
"10"    "0"
"30"    "0"
"20"    "0"
"50"    "0"
"40"    "0"
NULL    "0"
"90"    "0"
"60"    "0"
```

I want make this result in sorted order by status.

Answer (score 2):

Add `order by` at the end. Than it effects the whole result. In your code it only effect the second part of the `union`

```
select Status, Count from (
SELECT v.STATUS, COUNT(v.STATUS) AS COUNT
FROM mdl_ctx_voucher v
WHERE 
MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(v.timecreated)) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND
MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(v.timemodified)) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND 
YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(v.timecreated)) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND 
YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(v.timemodified)) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY v.STATUS 
)
UNION
(
SELECT DISTINCT(STATUS),0 as count
FROM mdl_ctx_voucher
WHERE STATUS NOT IN (
SELECT mainQuery.status
FROM 
(
SELECT COUNT(v.STATUS) AS COUNT, v.STATUS
FROM mdl_ctx_voucher v
WHERE 
MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(v.timecreated)) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(v.timemodified)) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(v.timecreated)) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(v.timemodified)) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY v.STATUS 
)mainQuery) 
)ORDER BY status DESC
```

Comment: He might need a `SELECT * FROM` at the beginning as well, doesn't he?

Comment: @Jens Thanks. Working fine. But a small question. How can i get the ids from the same query.

Comment: @chaitanya You can try to add `Group_concat(id)` to the select clause

Comment: No, you do not need to wrap the union into a subquery to be able sort the entire resultset